# General Question about the usage of For Loops And Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am currently trying to learn recursion and working on making my own `JSON.stringify` function using recursion. So far, I have not used any `for loops` for any of the problems I have done. Is using a `for loop` allowed in a recursion? Example of my code.

```
function stringify(object) {
  var string = '{';
  for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj[key] === undefined) {
        return string += '}';
      } else {
        return string += key.toString() + obj[key].toString() + stringify(object);
      }
  }
}
```

Now I know that when `stringify(object)` executes that it'll start the `for loop` all over again at the first property of `object` which results in an endless loop. My question is can a `for loop` be used when trying to make a function using recursion? Or should I change my approach to this problem and avoid a `for loop`. I'm just really looking for a guidance on an approach to this problem rather than any direct code answers. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you would often have a loop of some kind in a recursive function. Another way of organizing it might be to have the function take the first element found in the object then recursively pass the remainder to itself. But a loop is a more obvious way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

your if condition never goes true , so it always executes the else statement and calls it's self again .
when using recursions you should consider an end condition , which when your loop reaches the condition , doesn't call itself anymore .
in your example , you should call the function when it reaches an object inside the given object , recursion ends when there is no object left.
currently you are calling entire object again inside itself , it results in an infinite loop

```js
      var myObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: { r: 4, t: 5 } };

      function stringify(object) {
        let string = "";
        for (let key in object) {
          string +=
            key.toString() +
            " : [" +
            (typeof object[key] == "object"
              ? stringify(object[key])
              : object[key].toString()) +
            "] " ;
        }
        return string;
      }

      console.log(stringify(myObj));
```

Comment: I guess I am just confused about using a for loop in a recursion function. Wouldn't I be looping through the first property of the object every time once I called my recursion? What I mean by that is that when I did recursion for an array I would be able to slice the first element when calling the recursion allowing me to move through my array. For an object however, I don't understand how it's able to go through each property of the object if it's calling the same object again without removing any properties.

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis i am not sure what you are trying to understand , nothing is going to be removed or changed inside the object . we loop through an object , outputting property and value , however , if value is an object itself , we pass it to the function so function loops through it and outputs it's properties and values , returning the result . the results sits in the place of function where we called in , inside concatenation then continues the first looping . the point is that you have to have a condition when using recursions , so it doesn't repeat itself infinitely

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis in your code , you are passing the main object to the function instead of the inside object , that's why your function becomes an infinite recursion , look your code , you will get it , calling Object to function , inside it , you call it again with same object , that's why it loops for ever

Comment: "your if condition never goes true" -- it can go true e.g. if `obj = {k: undefined}`

Comment: @Stuart yes in that case it can happen but , hes calling the function `stringify(object) ` and inside it , instead of `stringify(obj[key])` he is again calling `stringify(object) ` . so the same value passed to function , the same execution happens , else statement executes again and calls himself with similar value again

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. Aren't I suppose to be passing in my main object again for recursion? Or am I supposed to be passing in each key from the iteration of the for loop? My confusion lies in that for arrays: I would pass in the main argument array but pass in `array.slice(1)` so that my recursion function would in take a new array after each element in the array. I don't get how to iterate through an object in the same way as that. Sorry, I just really don't understand how to do objects through recursion

Comment: it depends on your function and what it does , calling function is causing it's script to be executed again , what you pass to it , is a parameter , which can be variable , your function takes an object as parameter and stringifies it . if there is an object inside your main object , you need to call your function again with **new object ( new parameter )** so your function stringifies the child object and outputs the string  . if you call your function with same object , execution is same , trace your code you will get it .

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to do this without a loop, you could do something like this:

```
function stringify(obj, raw) {
  let [[k, v], ...rest] = Object.entries(obj), // Take the first entry and the rest
    r = k + ": ";

  // Process the first entry in the object  
  if (typeof v == "object") {
    r += stringify(v); // recursively call for inner objects
  }
  else {
    r += v;
  }

  // Process the remaining entries (if there are more)
  if (rest.length) {
    r += ", " + stringify(Object.fromEntries(rest), true);  // recursively call for remainder of present object
  }

  // Wrap the string in {} if needed
  if (raw) {
    return r;
  }
  else {
    return "{" + r + "}";
  }

}

console.log(stringify({x: 10, y: 5, params: {a: 3, b: 4}}));
```

One disadvantage is that for large objects you could run into maximum recursion depth issues. That could be avoided by having a loop within the recursive function. You also have to think about how you would deal with arrays (ignored in the code above).